# power of radical of ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, radicals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring.
Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Let radical of $I$, $J＝√I$.
Then, I'm wondering $J^n⊂I$ for some positive integer $n$?

I don't see whether this is true or not. There may be some counterexamples.

References are also appreciated.

P.S
　Thank you for counterexample. If $R$ is Noether, the statement is correct? Any reference is also appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if R si noetherian, this is true. So the counterexample should be a non-noetherian ring R

Comment: You need J to finitely generated, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $R=k[x_1,x_2,\dots]$ for a field $k$ (the polynomial ring in countably infinite many variables.) Take $I=(x_1,x_2^2,x_3^3,\dots)$. Then $J=\sqrt{I}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$, but $J^n$ is not contained in $I$ for any $n$.

Comment: $x_1$ is useless in this context.

Comment: Thank you for counterexample, if R is Noether, I would be grateful if you could tell me the hints or reference?

Comment: @Nekojiru In that case, since $J$ is finitely generated, say by $f_1,\cdots, f_r$, then take $N$ such that $f_i^N\in I$. Now use binomial expansion and suitable  $M$ (I will leave that as exercise) so that $M$^th power of any linear combination of $f_i$'s is in $I$.